# RxJs6 - Static merge an array of observables

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs6

I have a list of objects created dynamically by the user. Each object has a `click$` observable, I want to merge all this `click$` streams in one stream.

I've tried the `merge` static operator from `rxjs` import. With the direct references to the stream:

```
sub = merge(list[0].click$, list[1].click$)
    .subscribe(e => { 
       console.log('My click event', e); 
    })
```

all goes as expected.

But when I use an array of `click$` in the subscribe next call I received an `Observable` object and not my click event.

```
const streams= [];
list.forEach(o => { streams.push(o.click$); });

sub = merge(streams).subscribe(e => {
  console.log(e); // e is an observable ???
});
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Here a similar implementation with the same error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ohq6rx?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's an array. You can spread an array with the `...` operator in JavaScript. If you do this all should work well.

More information can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

I added code so you have an idea what I mean. List is the array of objects that have `click$` properties. this array is mapped to just the `click$` and then spread with the `...` operator.

`sub = merge(...list.map(item => item.click$)).subscribe(console.log)`